# Converting from string to float creates unnecessary decimals

Tags: c++, mfc

```
p->GetText(buf2,32);
float area = atof(buf2);
```

When I get say `9.2` in `buf2`, it gets automatically converted to `9.245`.

Can someone tell me why does this happen, (I have restricted my float value upto 3 decimal places)?

Comment: Well that certainly shouldn't be happening. But the code you've displayed does not indicate the problem.

Comment: I am taking the value in buf2 from an edit box .

Comment: Just to see what happens try `float area = atof("9.2");`. Does that also result in `9.245` ?

Comment: `GetText()` is not a member of the MFC [CEdit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75bh1f1t(v=vs.90).aspx) control. You must have a derived CEdit class with GetText() implemented or a local dialog class function doing something special. Your question can't be answered without knowing what GetText() does.